# Imgur access token expire time so long (315360000 second or millisecond?)

Tags: imgur

First, I must emphasize that in [Imgur](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest) Oauth2.0 step, Imgur deprecate the `code` response_type, only `token` response_type can be use, this means we can get access token directly once the user authorized(while in standard step, we can only get the `code` from user auth, and must use the `code` to exchange access token).

So, let's begin, I redirect to this link in the browser:

```
https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID
```

Imgur will show a consent screen, if I click `Agree`, it will redirect to the `REDIRECT_URL` that I fill in while registration and bring back some parameters, which is like this:

```
https://www.example.com/auth/ImgurRedirect.php#access_token=1bb250************745f0e&expires_in=315360000&token_type=bearer&refresh_token=604edb0*******e35f670d2&account_username=xi*****uce&account_id=9*****21
```

Now you can see, `expires_in=315360000`, god,315360000 seconds? 315360000/3600/24 = 3650 days = 10 years, I want to say, 10 years? are you kidding me?

My question: Is this normal? Is this a bug? Or is that the unit is millisec(but even the unit is millisec, this expire time is still as long as 3.65 days, it's not normal I think)?

Comment: That's odd. The docs say access tokens expire after a month, but the factor of 365 in there definitely suggests years.

Comment: It might be for the refresh_token - the docs say those don't expire. I'm confused by how all the expires_in values in the examples are 3600, though - that's an hour.

Comment: @ user2357112 supports Monica  Yeah, all the `expires_in` values are 3600 sec, not just Imgur. As far as I know, refresh_token have no expire time, unless the consent screen show again, otherwise refresh token will not expire, so I think expire time is not for the refresh token but for access token.